# JQuery click event for multiple elements with same ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have HTML page having below structure of div elements.

```
<div data-videos-list="listelement" id="band-comments-div">
<label>
    <!-- Some code here-->
    <br><a class="band-comments" href="review.html?bandName=Local Band">Click to review</a>
</label>
```

Here, div and a tags are repeated multiple times. The only difference between each anchor tag is that href attribute is different for each.
I am trying to handle the click event of every occurrence of the  tag like below.

```
$("#band-comments-div a").on("click", function(event) {
event.preventDefault();

}});
```

But since there are multiple occurrences of the div and a tags, the click event is not tracked. Is there any other way to handle this?

Comment: You can't have multiple tags with the same `id`. You need to use `class`

Comment: Yeah, duplicate IDs in a document is invalid HTML.

Comment: You can use onclick and pass the value. And You can't use same id multiple time.

Comment: @Eddie: I tried putting class attribute for div tag instead of id. and modified the code as : $(".band-comments a").on("click", function(event). But still, it is not able to track the specific a tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot give ID to multiple elements. You need to use class. Since you are giving multiple IDs it will only track the click event of first occurrence. You can do something like this.

```
<div data-videos-list="listelement" class="band-comments-div">
<label>
    <!-- Some code here-->
    <br><a class="band-comments" href="review.html?bandName=Local Band">Click to review</a>
</label>


$(docunment).on("click",".band-comments-div a", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  alert($(this).attr("href"));
});
```

This way you can get the attr `href` of each `a` tag on click event.

### Update

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var href = ''; 
 $(docunment).on("click",".band-comments-div a", function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
      href = $(this).attr("href");
  });
  alert(href);
});
```

Comment: This is the perfect solution! Thanks!

Comment: Is there any way to track the href of clicked a tag outside the click handler function. Earlier I had a single a tag and for that, I was using $(#id).currentTarget. But it is not working for multiple occurrences.

Comment: I didn't get you. Can you please explain what are you trying to achieve? @Swaps

Comment: I was trying to use the href attribute of the clicked anchor tag outside the click event handler. It worked in the same way to track the click event.

Comment: Check updated answer. let me know if it works for you? @Swaps

Comment: I got it! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Your links have **band-comment** class. You can use it:

```
$(".band-comments").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('clicked!');
});
```

Working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cr29y1tc/410/).

Comment: This is quick and smart solution.

Answer (score 2):

You cant use same id with multiple HTML elements. You need to use `class`

If you are trying to `e.preventDefault();` the `<a>` inside the `<div>`, you can use the selector `$(".band-comments-div a")`

```js
$(".band-comments-div a").click(function(e) {
  console.log("-> " + $(this).attr('href') );
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="band-comments-div"><a href="http://google.com">1</a></div>
<div class="band-comments-div"><a href="http://yahoo.com">2</a></div>
<div class="band-comments-div"><a href="http://stackoverflow.com">3</a></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> But since there are multiple occurrences of the div and a tags, the
>   click event is not tracked.

Having duplicate ids causes problems - **this** is one of those.

> Is there any other way to handle this?

You can remove `id` attribute (*since I don't see how this is useful anyways as you can't use it in a selector*). **Use the `data-videos-list` attribute in the selector**

```
$("div[data-videos-list] a").on("click", function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   //rest of the logic
}});
```

If there are going to be multiple anchors in the div, then use anchor's class as well in the selector

```
$("div[data-videos-list] a.band-comments").on("click", function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   //rest of the logic
}});
```

Answer (score 1):

Non-unique IDs are invalid html so you should a class instead:

```js
$(".band-comments-div a").on("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(this.outerHTML);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-videos-list="listelement" class="band-comments-div">
  <label>
    <!-- Some code here-->
    <br><a class="band-comments" href="review.html?bandName=Local Band">Click to review</a>
</label>
```