# Flip card when clicking a link inside of if (just using CSS)

Tags: css

I should create a card that flips when clicking a link inside of it. Just using HTML/CSS. So I have created a div, that contains two divs, and each of those divs contain one link. This way:

```css
#btnLeft {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
    transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

#uno {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#dos {
  background-color: red;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);

}

 #uno, #dos {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

#btnLeft:target {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="btnLeft">
  <div id="uno">
    <a href="#btnLeft">hello</a>
  </div>
  <div id="dos">
    <a href="#btnLeft">hola</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem: it works perfect when clicking "hello" but it doesn't work when clicking "hola", why since both of them have `id="btnLeft"`?

Comment: The problem is with: `transform: rotateY(180deg);` it will not  add 180deg each time you're targeting it. First time it will rotate, then it will see that it's already rotated `180deg` so it won't rotate again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you have the same id for both links. Change one of the id's and it works fine.

```
<div id="btnLeft">
  <div id="uno">
    <a href="#btnLeft">hello</a>
  </div>
  <div id="dos">
    <a href="#btnRight">hola</a>
  </div>
</div>

#btnLeft:target {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/24vxkfe6/

Here are some links. HOpe this helps.

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49606547/jquery-click-event-for-multiple-a-tags-with-same-id)

[here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really)

Comment: thanks, but can you explain a bit why it works? I still can not understand it

Comment: Because it's only targeting the first id. When you are use an event vs something, it will only hit the first id, not anything past it.

Comment: can you paste any link about what you say? I still don't understand completely.

Comment: I added some links for you. Hope it helps.

Comment: I know that you can not assign to two elelements the same `id`. My question is more about why it flips when clicking "hola".

Comment: The id is still there so it's getting "targeted" its just flipped on the backface. Do me a favor, open up the fiddle and inspect the element when it's flipped ( showing hola ). You'll see its still being selected because it's higher on the plain. All backface-visiblity is doing is showing the back side of the element.

Comment: @ziiweb because when you click on a different anchor will enable another `:target` (that simply doesn't exist here) and will disable the actual one

Comment: @TemaniAfif ok, so if there is a link in the same page, when clicking that link the `div` will also flip.. that is not so good.. any way to prevent it?

Comment: @ziiweb instead of adding another anchor simply consider an empty one `href="#"`